# In React, how can I keep the states inside a useCallback up-to-dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have a state named `questions` In a React component.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
```

and a `useEffect` method that runs only when the component is rendered the first time.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let questionsArray = [];
  //some work is done here to populate the questionsArray
  setQuestions(questionsArray);
},[]);
```

I have a `useCallback` method that is created when the component is rendered for the first time.

```
const updateQuestion = useCallback(() =>{
  let new_questions = [...questions];
  //do some work here
},[]);
```

The problem is that questions state inside the `updateQuestion` callback is empty because when the component is rendered the first time, the questions state is empty, and the `updateQuestion` callback uses the stale questions state for some reason. However, the `useEffect` populates the questions state array, and the questions state inside `updateQuestion` callback is not up-to-date. I solved this problem by adding `questions.length` to the dependencies array of `useCallback` like the following

```
const updateQuestion = useCallback((index) =>{
  let new_questions = [...questions];
  //do some work here
},[questions.length]);
```

So, when the questions state is populated with new data in the `useEffect`, the `updateQuestion` callback is re-created, and the `useCallback` will have up-to-date data in questions state. But, are there any other ways that I can get the up-to-date questions state inside the `useCallback` without re-creating the callback?

Each item in questions array is used to render a child components named QuestionCard

```
questions.map((question, index)=>{
        return  (
            <li className="list-group-item border-0" key={question.id}>
               <QuestionCard props={question} index={index} updateQuestion={updateQuestion} />
             </li>
             );
        })
```

The problem is that QuestionCard is a memoized component. If I append an item to the questions state array, the existing items in questions state are the same, they don't need to be rerendered. Now, If i pass questions.array into the dependencies array, the callback is re-created, every child components is rerendered. But, I can't just skip using useCallback and just create a native function. Because, updateQuestion callback is used to update individual question item insides the questions array. If I update a single question, every question will be rerender. If I use useCallback, only the question i am updating is rerendered while i am updating it .

Comment: Why not just `[questions]`? If the content changes but the length doesn't, then you'd have a problem using your approach of `questions.length`.

Comment: because, the questions state is a list of data that will be used to render a list of Child components. If I update any of the data in any item of the questions array, the callback will be recreated, and the callback is passed to each Child components that are memoized.  Passing [questions] will rerender every memoized child component. @ggorlen

Comment: Isn't that what you want? Otherwise, those child components would have stale questions, no? I think more detail and preferably a [mcve] is needed here.

Comment: @ggorlen I am just wondering if I am able to keep the states inside a useCallback up-to-date without re-creatinng the callback and pass anything to the dependencies array. If I append an item to the questions state array, the existing items in questions state are the same, they don't need to be rerendered. Now, If i pass questions.array into the dependencies array, the callback is re-created, every child components is rerendered

Comment: If that's the case, just skip using `useCallback` entirely. The function will be created each render and use the current value of any state

Comment: @Phil I can't. Because, updateQuestion callback is used to update individual question item insides the questions array. If I update a single question, every question will be rerender. If I use useCallback, only the question i am updating is rerendered while i am updating it

Comment: @Rongeegee then your approach is incorrect. useCallback is not intended for this purpose. Instead of passing the `updateQuestion` as callback, make it local to the Question component and pass the `question` state and its update function as props or context.

Comment: @EternalObserver are you saying I need to update the question data in each QuestionCard component locally? Well, I also need to update it in the questions state in parent component? Can I update the state of parent component in a child component without passing a callback to a child component?

Comment: @Rongeegee using memoized child - QuestionCard component with useMemo will not render every question , only new updated question will be re rendered .
I created sample codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-framework-g8z8kq?file=/src/App.js
Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: @NagaSaiA put a useEffect that has console.log(index) in your questionCard compoent. You will see that the questionCards are rerendered each time you add a new question

Comment: @Rongeegee you can use Context API for updating state inside parent if the nesting is deep and you don't want to pass callbacks as props.

Comment: @Rongeegee, i added console log and seeing console log only once for new added question and not displaying multiple console logs - https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-framework-g8z8kq?file=/src/QuestionCard.js
That single re render is required for showing new question

Comment: @NagaSaiA inside your addQuestions method, you call setQuestions. doesn't it modify the questions state which in turn triggers the re-creation of updateQuestion callback?

Comment: It will trigger recreation but it is only for new question card but not for memorized question card component@Rongeegee… if you try to print question card props .. you will not seeing loaded question card props and only new card props will be printed

Comment: @NagaSaiA actually in QuestionCard, change remove the dependency array from useEffect and put console.log(index). You will every questionCard has a console.log executed if you add a new questionCard